# How to Set default value in a loop of formControls in HTML?

Tags: html, angular

I have an array of input elements with formControl Directive. I have set the value of each element with value attribute, but it showing blank. If I set the value in ts file, the same value will be set in each and every element. So, how to differentiate the elements if I have to set value in ts?

Here is my code:

HTML code:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="amount">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Amount
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="onEditClick(datasource.data)">
            <mat-icon style="cursor: pointer;" class="ml-2 mr-2" >edit</mat-icon>
        </button>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i=index;">
        <ng-container *ngIf="isActual">{{row.amount || "-- --"}}</ng-container>
            <mat-form-field *ngIf="isEditMonth" class="example-full-width month-textbox" appearance="outline">
                <input #elRef matInput type="text" [formControl]="amountField" (change)="onAmountChanged($event,row)" [value]="row.amount">
            </mat-form-field>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

TS Code:

```js
amountField = new FormControl();
```

Answer (score 0):

The default value of the select element can be set by using the `selected` attribute on the required option. This is a boolean attribute meaning if the  `selected` attribute is present the element will be displayed by default on the dropdown list.

Comment: This is input element, not a select one.

Answer (score 0):

this.form.controls['amountField'].setValue("Value you want to be selected");

You can set the value by using this.

Comment: I have a loop of elements in HTML. So how to set value by defining one formControl in a loop